# Как синхронизировать apache2 с Django проектом

Tags: python, django, apache2, apache-modules, mod-wsgi

Поделитесь пожалуйста 'рецептом' синхронизации веб-сервера Apache 2 с Django проектом. Использую Ubuntu 16.04, Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu).
Django версии 1.9.

Вот, что я пробовал (из документации Django):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / home/anton/projects/django_dir/films/films/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/anton/projects/django_dir/films

<Directory /home/anton/projects/django_dir/films/films>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Это файл /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
Ошибку при запросе `localhost` выдает следующую:

> Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Содержимое моего wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "films.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Что значит синхронизировать?

Comment: @andreymal это значит что Django проектом используется веб-сервер apache, а не manage.py runserver. То есть клиент (браузер) будет взаимодействовать с apache.

Comment: Про это не только навалом в гугле, но и в официальной документации django есть, не?

Comment: @andreymal да, есть довольно много. Но я уже многое перепробовал там (и как ни странно не работает, в том числе из официальной документации). Не буду же я оставлять вопрос на stackoverflow предварительно не прогуглив его.

Comment: Не будете же вы оставлять вопрос на stackoverflow, предварительно не объяснив, что именно вы пробовали и почему оно не получилось ;)

Comment: «More information about this error may be available in the server error log.» — Очевидно, нужно открыть log и прочитать more information :)